# Settings.xml won’t let me change background color?

Tags: java, android, xml, background, settings

I've done this before...not sure what i'm doing wrong now I know it's the simplest thing in the world but i just want to make the text of my settings page black and the background white. Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong? my code does nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <CheckBoxPreference 
    android:summary="summary goes here" 
    android:title="Preference 1"
    android:defaultValue="false" 
    android:key="one"
    android:textColor="#000000">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

FYI, I've tried #AARRGGBB it doesn't change anything. If i use the exact same android:background="#FFFFFF" in any layout file it works great. I just don't know why it's not working here :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand there is no way to change the look and feel of a preference activity.
I just wrote the whole thing again just to have a custom UI and to show a text beyond the settings in one of my apps.

Some people recommend to add another theme to the preference activity in the manifest. You could try it with the light theme of Android first. That should be:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!